# document.createElements Throws InvalidCaracterError Exception

Tags: javascript, dom

Every time I'm trying to use the method document.createElements I receive the exception InvalidCaracterError. I changed my input to a constant string and even thought it is still doesn't works. Help will be very appreciable, please review attached image. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'checkbox';
```

You cannot just pass it a string containing a tag like in jquery.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) only takes the element name, not actual HTML, so use:

```
var oObj = document.createElement('input');
oObj.type = 'checkbox';
```